# ServiceStack how to customize logout?

Tags: servicestack, logout

ServiceStack how to customize logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/auth/logout` logs out the [Session identified by the Session Cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) which are automatically added to the HTTP Client after it successfully authenticates.

You can [specify which session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/433368a6a45d29ec751c09ad2f21d1b30ee73377/src/ServiceStack/SessionExtensions.cs#L61) each request is for with either:

- the `X-ss-id` or `X-ss-pid` HTTP Headers
- Temporary `ss-id` or Permanent `ss-pid` Cookies (send ss-opt=perm to indicate permanent session id)

Or if `AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams` was enabled:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams = true });
```

The Session Cookies can also be added to the `?ss-id` or `?ss-pid` QueryString or POST'ed FormData for the request.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm this. If I log in with two users and I will have two sessions. Let's say their ss-id are xxxx and yyyy. So /auth/logout?ss-id=xxxx will log out session xxxx but no session yyyy? So I could still access services with session yyyy? Thanks.

Comment: @user5506787 it only logs out the 1 specified session. Note to enable specifying session id via ?queryString you need to enable `AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams=true`.